# Why doe's fixed positioned div is scrolling instead of staying in the specified location?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-position, positioning

I usually find answers here for every problem, but couldn't find this:

I'm trying to make a div to be fixed to `top:50px`.

However, when I scroll the page, this Div is scrolling up and the mentioned position is only applied as sort of a minimum scrolling position...

html:

```
  <div class="homepage-hugger">
    <div class="home-box" id="home-box-1">
      --- Div's Content ---
    </div>
   --- some more stuff ---
</div>
```

JavaScript successfully adds the following css to the `#home-box-1` Div:

```
$("#home-box-1").css({"position": "fixed", "top" : "50px"});
```

The result css is of course:

```
position: fixed; top: 50px;
```

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**
Maybe more of my code will help...
So this is the css (scss) for `.homepage-hugger` and `.home-box`:

```
.homepage-hugger{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

  .home-box{
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

And the full related JavaScript that works as expected (it includes some unrelated code for other scrolling behavior) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function mobileCats(){
    var catOffset = $("#home-box-1").offset().top;
    var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var boxPos = catOffset - winScroll;
    console.log(boxPos <= 50);
    if (boxPos <= 50){
      $("#home-box-1").css({"position": "fixed", "top" : "50px", "left" : "0px"});
    }
  }

  mobileCats();

$(window).scroll(function()
        {
      mobileCats();
            var x = $(this).scrollTop(); /* scroll pos */
            var y = $("html").height();
            var z = x / y;

            curTop = ((z*500));
            $(".main-banners").css("top", (curTop)+"px");
        });
});
```

Comment: That should work... would you be able to create a demo/fiddle?

Comment: It's seems that works. I Just created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4p2b0oqL/

Comment: this should work. Try setting left and right to 0, check if it helps.

Comment: I think this may be an issue of expected behavior.  Sierion, can you confirm that what you see in @Asjon 's link is what you want?

Comment: Yes @Asjon , This is what I want and I have done this before. I can't understand why it doesn't work this time.  @sana , I tried adding `left` positioning without luck. weird, huh..?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I was able to find that `position: fixed` and `transform: translate()` could not be stacked due to mathematical reasons behind the scenes.

A class added by an add-on to a parent Div has added a `transform: translate()` style to it which made the `position: fixed` of the child Div impossible to compute.

To issue was resolved by taking the fixed Div out of all containers, putting it directly under `body` and repositioning it.

Thank you all for trying to help. appreciated.